# Windows Security Alert for netsession_win.exe

Tags: windows-vista, firewall, windows-firewall

My Windows Firewall blocked "netsession_win.exe" because it was accepting incoming network connections.

I have no clue what this program does.  Should I allow the incoming connection?

BTW the publisher is Unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible link to live video has been reported over the last couple of days. It is possible that you have no firewall set on your router.

Enter this in search - it has an uninstaller at this location:

```
C:\users\Your_User_Name\appdata\local\akamai\
```

I do not know if you should let it pass. That would depend on what you would need it for, if at all.

[This site](http://www.akamai.com/html/misc/akamai_client/netsession_interface_faq.html) claims to be the source. All information was from [this site](http://truxtertech.com/news/) and it has much more  detail. It does not sound like it is a highly dangerous type, but you can never be too careful.

Comment: +1 -complete answer. I'm not sure, does it sound dangerous? Do you have it running?

Comment: i do not have it installed, if you have any concerns do not install, it does come with a .exe uninstall and may be part of your internet life, but it is a bad way to get your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It is reported to be harmless, but no one remembers ever authorizing the software to install. I myself uninstalled it and everything has been running fine since. 
I have been told that other people are using this software, bundled with some new virus, it's yet another exploit using someone's harmless software.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has a write up of this that can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIMyComputerWhatIsNetsessionwinexeFromAkamaiAndHowDidItGetOnMySystem.aspx). He explains how he found it and what he's found out about it.

Summary seems to be that it is signed by Akamai (CDN company) and probably bundled as part of Flash. What it does we don't know! It's official website is [here](http://www.akamai.com/client).